# Laravel 5.4 migration error [42501]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can create migration. It's working fine but when I do php artisan migrate it says

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

I checked my `database.php` file and it's working fine and already migrated default users table too to my php my admin mysql.

Comment: If you've already migrated the users table, go into the users migration file and comment everything in the `up` function. Be sure to uncomment everything after you've migrated.

Comment: but this time im not migrating user table im migrating POST table which is not working , i can create more migrations different names but when i try to migrate it gives me this error i dont know why

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't see that you'd already migrated that file. Maybe it's not listed in migrations, or you did a `migrate:rollback` that partially failed, but still removed line out of the migrations table. Commenting it temporarily helps the migrations table get up-to-date.

Comment: i was see this problem before and you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270874/how-can-i-do-a-migration-in-laravel-5-5

Answer (score 1):

Delete all tables form the software (phpmyadmin) and then migrate again this will migrate the new created table , this is not a proper solution but this worked here on learning level , Regards

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is: `php artisan migrate:refresh`

⚠️ **You will lose all data in your tables!** ⚠️

[More info in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#running-migrations).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sentence in the **UsersTableSeeder** to regenerate the table:

```
DB::table('users')->truncate();
```