# How can I do a migration in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration

I've created an Auth project with **laravel 5.5** and created new migration and when I migrate I receive this error msg:

In Connection.php line 647:

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
(SQL: create table `users` (
      `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
      `name` varchar(255) not null,
      `username` varchar(255) not null,
      `email` varchar(255) not null,
      `password` varchar(255) not null,
      `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
      `created_at` timestamp null,
      `updated_at` timestamp null,
      `role` int not null
      ) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
)
```

In Connection.php line 449:

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
```

i try php artisan migrate --force and php artisan migrate:rollback

and try to drop all tabels and migrate it again and still ahve this error

Comment: which RDBMS is used here? you tagged 2 different ones.

Comment: i used mysql @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: Just go into your database and delete all the tables or you can delete the user's table and go to the migration table and delete the user's migration row and then run `php artisan migrate` again

Comment: Can you list all the migrations you have in your project? You probably have two migrations that are both trying to create the `users` table.

Comment: @Yosef thanks but i do this step more time and still have same error

Comment: @NirajShah 
list of migration 
1-        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('role');
        });

Comment: @NirajShah

2-        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
3-        Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->text('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading error msg in CMD (DOS) and check laravel documentation

error in length i dont know if any one see this error before or not but when i edit length its work

i edit 3 migration as below :-

```
1 -1- Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id'); $table->string('name'); $table->string('username')->unique(); $table->string('email')->unique(); $table->string('password'); $table->rememberToken(); $table->timestamps(); $table->integer('role'); });
```

and now its

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('name',200);
        $table->string('username',50)->unique();
        $table->string('email',100)->unique();
        $table->string('password',50);
        $table->string('role',50);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

number 2 it was

```
 Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->string('email')->index(); $table->string('token'); $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable(); });
```

and now its :-

```
        Schema::create('passwordreset', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email',200)->index();
        $table->string('token',200);
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    });
```

number 3 it was :-

```
3- Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id'); $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index(); $table->text('text'); $table->timestamps(); });
```

now its :-

```
        Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('user_id',50)->index();
        $table->string('twetts',255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18553311)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai im the author of problem and i found solution by check  laravel DOC

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a database that already has a `users` table, but no `migration` table. Therefore, when you run the migration, it's attempting to create the `users` table again.

There are two things you can try:

1) Try setting up a new (empty) database in MySQL and update the settings in your `.env` file to point to this new DB. Run `php artisan migrate` and see if your migrations are correctly applied.

2) Using your existing database, delete / drop all tables (make a backup of the data if you want to retain it), and then run `php artisan migrate` and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

to understand the problem and find a solution you need to understand how migration works. migrations work on a creation date basis way. whenever a migration is created the current time stamp is append to the file name. and migration runs according to that time stamp.
NOW LARAVEL creates two migrations named 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php and 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php. as the rule of laravel whenever you are going to  run migration these two files are going to migrate but users table already exists. delete these to files and hope your problem will be solved.
one thing, if you are handling databse in laravel using schema and migrations do not ever delete db manually. it will cause you unnecessary problems. the migration table keeps track of all the migrations you run and deleting db manually will break that  track of keeping data in migrations table. so next time you run a schema, laravel would not be able to understand whats going on and will create errors.
hope that will help you.

Comment: check your database, you already have a users table. so the migration is throwing the error. just remove your users table migration file and see. or else you can run a rollback. see that helps. and let me know.

Comment: Problem its about length of cell

Comment: yes now its solved by add length of cell
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a new migration for the table 'users'?

Laravel by default when a new project is created will produce a migration for a users table. This will mean if you create a new migration with the 'users' table it will try to create the table twice hence causing the error.

You can either remove the laravel created migration, change the name of your new table or modify the laravel migration rather than creating your own.

Comment: Delete the users migration from your project then run "_php artisan migrate --fresh_"

Comment: I deleted it more and more and problem in cell length